# Is rotation a requirement for iPad apps?

Tags: ipad, rotation

Is it a requirement for iPad apps to be able to rotate?

I am looking at a few apps, one example is http://squareup.com they only have one rotation, while others have rotation. What is the exact spec?

Comment: Speaking as an iPad owner, I don't buy apps that don't support rotation.

Comment: Belongs on User Interface, not StackOverflow.

Comment: If your app looks good in both orientations then use both.
Your layout might inspire you to restrict to one orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not required but I've seen apps butchered for it in reviews. I believe I saw that for the app Facepad.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to support rotation; however almost all apps do.

Answer (score 2):

At least support 180° rotation. Preferably 360°, but this depends on the **content your app shows**. Fir example, Keynote offers only landscape \w 180° rotation because slideshows are always in landscape.

It's not a requirement, but how'd you like it if Safari didn't rotate? When designing a UI, imagine you are the user, the one you make the app for. How does the user like it? And make it like that.

Answer (score 2):

It's highly recommended to. If you don't want to do the work of re-laying-out your interface from portrait to landscape or vice versa, you can at least support the 180-degree rotation of whatever orientation you do want to use: landscape-right if it's set up for landscape-left, or portrait-upside-down if it's set up for portrait. It's the user-friendly thing to do and really not complicated to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think GarageBand suffers for not supporting it. It's right for it to be case-by-case