# Portrait or Landscape on iPad when submitting apps

Tags: ipad, itunes

Portrait or landscape on iPad when submitting apps? What is the requirement or can you use either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708687/is-rotation-a-requirement-for-ipad-apps/4708927#4708927), it's not required that you use both, but highly recommended.

*EDIT* Just realized that you might be asking about the screenshots, whether they should be portrait or landscape. As far as I know, they could be either. I've submitted iPad apps that have both portrait and landscape screenshots.